# Get a list of subnets matching a given CIDR

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm trying to take a known subnet ID and CIDR mask, e.g., 10.0.0.0/22, and get a list like this:

```
[('10.0.0.0', '10.0.3.255'),
('10.0.4.0', '10.0.7.255'),
...
('10.255.252.0', '10.255.255.255')]
```

I've tried a few existing modules like `ipcalc`, but it doesn't seem to have a feature like that. I'm not sure what kind of math is necessary for me to write my own module to do it, either.

Comment: `10.0.0.0/22`'s network address is `10.0.0.0`, broadcast address is `10.0.3.255`. Other addresses are outside the network.

Comment: @falsetru I know, what I'm trying to do is get a list of all subnets the fall under the first octet and match the /22 mask.

Comment: @Soviero actually you are mistaken in that the first octet does not make sense anymore (it is not special).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is to me, cause I'm only looking for private addresses in the 10.*.*.* space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module if you use Python 3.3+:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> it = ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.0.0/8').subnets(new_prefix=22)
>>> networks = [(str(n.network_address), str(n.broadcast_address)) for n in it]
>>> len(networks)
16384
>>> networks[0]
('10.0.0.0', '10.0.3.255')
>>> networks[-1]
('10.255.252.0', '10.255.255.255')
```

In Python 2.x, use [`ipaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr):

```
>>> import ipaddr
>>> it = ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/8').subnet(new_prefix=22)
>>> networks = [(str(n.network), str(n.broadcast)) for n in it]
>>> len(networks)
16384
>>> networks[0]
('10.0.0.0', '10.0.3.255')
>>> networks[-1]
('10.255.252.0', '10.255.255.255')
```

**UPDATE**

There's Python 2.7 backport of Python 3.3 ipaddress: [`py2-ipaddress`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress/).

Comment: @Soviero, I added another version that can be used in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 5):

Use the new [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.subnets) module in Python 3.3:

```
import ipaddress

for i in ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.0.0/8').subnets(new_prefix=22):
    print(i)
```